# Ubuntu 18.04: getting "Unable to get list of updates" in Ubuntu Software

Tags: 18.04, software-center

I'm constantly getting notification "Unable to get list of updates" when hitting reload button in "Updates" tab.
When running `sudo apt update` it will not produce any error.
Below is what I get from `syslog` when I hit that reload button:

```
Jan 24 21:27:06 arakir-G750JX PackageKit: get-updates transaction /500_acbddace from uid 1000 finished with success after 497ms
Jan 24 21:27:06 arakir-G750JX gnome-software[4386]: failed to call gs_plugin_refresh on shell-extensions: Failed to parse '(null)': server returned no data
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the same bug: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-software/issues/339

It seems the original bug reporter disappeared. Can you please provide Richard Hughes with the log that he asks for? Thanks.